# Error in creating Python AWS Lambda deployment package for python-docx library on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, package, python-docx

I am relatively new to AWS Lambda and Python. Trying to create a deployment package for AWS Lambda using python-docx library on Windows for Python 3.8. It is failing with the error - cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml'.

If the precompiling python-docx library is the solution, then can somebody please provide more information on this. Because the information I could find on this was 3 years old and for Python 2.7.

Note: To verify my package creation steps, I tried to create the deployment package just for requests package and it worked fine. Later on, updated the same python function to include python-docx and it is still failing with the above error.

Comment: Sounds like the (binary) `lxml` package is not getting into the package. You might search on `lxml AWS package` or similar to see what the challenges with that might be.

Comment: lxml is present in the deployment package. On doing, pip/pip3 install python-docx, lxml gets automatically installed in the environment. It seems like, lxml requires precompiling. Trying to find more about this.

Comment: You can refer to [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/) for creating a deployment package with precompiled binaries. Binaries for `lxml` can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files), download the one with "x86_64" and the correct python version.